# Azure: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined at exports.post

Tags: javascript, azure, mobile, service, promise

I am using azure mobile services, with following custom API:

```
var returnVal = new Object;


exports.post = function (request, response) {
    // Use "request.service" to access features of your mobile service, e.g.:
    //   var tables = request.service.tables;
    //   var push = request.service.push;

    var merchantdetailsTable = request.service.tables.getTable("merchantdetails");
    var resourceName;
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(request.parameters));
    merchantdetailsTable.insert({
        name: request.body.workerNameInput,
        emailid: request.body.workerEmailIDInput,
        contact: request.body.workerContactNumberInput
    }).then(function (merchantInserted) {
        returnVal.workerId = merchantInserted.id;
        resourceName = returnVal.workerId.toLowerCase();
        var shopworkersTable = request.service.tables.getTable("shopworkers");
        return shopworkersTable.insert({
            id: merchantInserted.id,
            shopid: request.body.shopId
        });
    }, function(err){
        return response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err);
    }).then(function () {
        var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
        var accountKey = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;
        var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';
        var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);
        return blobService.createContainerIfNotExists("merchant-image", { publicAccessLevel: 'blob' });
    }, function (err) {
        return response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err);
    }).then(function(error){
        if (!error) {
            // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins. 
            var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                AccessPolicy: {
                    Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                    Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
                }
            };

            // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new image.
            var sasQueryUrl =
         blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature("merchant-image",
         '', sharedAccessPolicy);
            // Set the query string.
         returnVal["merchantImage"].sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);

            // Set the full path on the new new item, 
            // which is used for data binding on the client. 
         returnVal["merchantImage"].imageUri = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path + '/'
                + resourceName;

         var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
         var accountKey = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;
         var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';
         var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);
         return blobService.createContainerIfNotExists("pharmacy-certificate", { publicAccessLevel: 'blob' });
        }
        else {
            return response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }, function (err) {
        return response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err);
    }).done(function (error) {

        if (!error) {
            // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins. 
            var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                AccessPolicy: {
                    Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                    Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
                }
            };

            // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new image.
            var sasQueryUrl =
         blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature("pharmacy-certificate",
         '', sharedAccessPolicy);
            // Set the query string.
            returnVal["pharmacyCertificate"].sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);

            // Set the full path on the new new item, 
            // which is used for data binding on the client. 
            returnVal["pharmacyCertificate"].imageUri = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path + '/'
                   + resourceName;
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, returnVal);
        }
        else {
            return response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }, function (err) {
        return response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err);
    });

    response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'Hello World!' });
};

exports.get = function(request, response) {
  response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'Hello World!' });
};
```

I am getting following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
>       at exports.post (D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\api\addWorker.js:17:8)

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried to isolate the problem?

Comment: So? Apparently `merchantdetailsTable.insert(…)` doesn't return a promise. Why do you think it should do? Do you have some API links for it?

Comment: Once you've sorted out the issue @Bergi noted, you may want to look at how you're chaining - almost every `then` has an onRejected callback which does exactly the same thing, **and** ensures that the next onFullfilled callback will be called

Comment: hi @Bergi, promises for azure are explained here [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#promises). if I use .done() with insert, it works perfectly fine. But, then() gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Services does not return promises from table operations. You need to pass an options object that contains success and error callbacks, as described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554210.aspx.

I highly recommend that you take a look at the newer implementation of the product, Azure Mobile Apps - https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-mobile-apps. (Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft on the Azure Mobile Apps team)